# DataStage 9.1 Parametric table name based in input file

Tags: datastage

i have to develop a 9.1 DataStage ETL process in which the same logic is applied to different input files, output table...

Based on the read input file fileA, fileB, fileC, I have to perform my job on the respective tables i.e. tableA, tableB, tableC

How I can achieve this requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Job Parameters as placeholders for both the input file name and the output table name.  Then pass the fileX and tableX values to said parameters at runtime.